# Combining commands for two major modes

Tags: list, conditionals

I want to extend the execution of the body of `emacs-lisp-mode` also to `lisp-interaction-mode`.  How can I combine two conditions together?

```
(cond

  ((eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode)
      (let ( (hrklevels tika-elisp-hrklevels) )
        (setq outline-regexp
              (concat (regexp-opt (mapcar 'car hrklevels)) "\\>"))
        (setq outline-heading-alist hrklevels)
        (setq-local outline-level 'outline-level)))

  ((eq major-mode 'f90-mode)
      (let ( (hrklevels tika-fortran-hrklevels) )
        (setq outline-regexp
              (concat (regexp-opt (mapcar 'car hrklevels)) "\\>"))
        (setq outline-heading-alist hrklevels))) )
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Combining-Conditions.html

Comment: My solution would then use  `(or (eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode) (eq major-mode 'lisp-interaction-mode))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(when (memq major-mode '(emacs-lisp-mode lisp-interaction-mode)) ...)
```

Comment: Here you use `(when` instead of `(or` ?

Comment: I am unsure whether `(cond ((when (memq major-mode '(emacs-lisp-mode lisp-interaction-mode))) (do-this) ))` actually works.

Comment: I use `when` and `unless` when I want to indicate to a human reader that the return value of the sexp is unimportant - the code is only used for its side effects.

Comment: Is that because the return value of `memq` is `non-nil` when there is a match ?

Comment: I have other major mode conditions, would I also use when for them. Currently I am using `cond`.  My understanding is that I have to remove the `cond` clause and perform a `when` for each different major made groupings.

Comment: condition in a cond clause also succeeds if the value is non-nil.

Comment: You can use `cond` to replace any `if`, `when`, `unless`, or `and` sexp.

Comment: `memq` returns non-nil when there is a match. But `when` always returns nil.